# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

new to programming and having problems trying to render a chart from a dummy data. This is the error " Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Undefined".
Basically send data from parent to child component and have it rendered. Having some trouble to send the data correctly dunno what to do. parent
`index.vue`

```
<template>
  <bar-chart/>
</template>
<script>
import BarChart from '../components/BarChart.vue'
import fake, { day, profit, total } from '../static/dummy'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { BarChart },
  data(){
    return {
     day : 0,
     profit : 0,
     total : 0,
      chartData: {},
    };
  },
  created(){
    this.getDataa();
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getDataa();
  },
  methods: {
    getDataa(){
      this.day = fake.day;
      this.profit = fake.profit;
      this.total = fake.total
      this.chartData = {
        labels: [this.day],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "profit",
            data: [this.profit],
            backgroundColor: '#90EE90'
          },
          {
            label: "total",
            data: [this.total],
            backgroundColor: '#68BBE3',
          }
        ],
      }
      },
    },
  computed: {
      getDay :function() {
        return this.day;
      },
      getProfit :function(){
        return this.profit;
      },
      getTotal: function(){
        return this.total;
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

child
`BarChart.vue`

```
<template>
  <bar-chart :chart-data ="chartData"></bar-chart>
</template>
<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'
ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  props:{
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              stacked: true,
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              stacked: true,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted (){
    console.log(this.chartData);
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
}
</script>
```

dummy data
`dummy.js`

```
  exports.day=[
    {
      id:1,
      day: "9/21",
    },
    {
      id:2,
      day: "9/22",
    },
    {
      id:3,
      day: "9/23",
    },
    {
      id:4,
      day: "9/24",
    },
    {
      id:5,
      day: "9/25",
    },
]
exports.profit = [
  {
    id:1,
    profit:"200",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    profit:"300",
  },
  {
    id:3,
    profit:"400",
  },
  {
    id:4,
    profit:"500",
  },
  {
    id:5,
    profit:"600",
  },
]
exports.total = [
  {
    id:1,
    total:"1000",
  },
  {
    id:2,
    total:"2000",
  },
  {
    id:3,
    total:"3000",

  },
  {
    id:4,
    total:"4000",
  },
  {
    id:5,
    total:"5000",
  },
]
```

Comment: Use your Vue devtools to debug efficiently. Here, you should probably use `<bar-chart :chart-data="chartData" />` aka pass the actual prop data to your component.

Comment: if possible can you show me it with a example ?

Comment: What do you want an example for? Passing the prop to the component? I just did in my comment above.

Comment: Also, maybe my initial comment wasn't clear enough but `:chart-data ="chartData"` needs to be on the parent, and not on the child itself. You do pass the data top to bottom, and you have `chartData` in the parent initially. The child is just receiving it, no need to use `:chart-data ="chartData"` since you do have the props received from the top.

Comment: it has the same error and when :chart-data = "chartData" is removed from child and added in parent gives a new error "render function or template not defined in component: BarChart"

Answer (score 0):

well problem was at different thing i use vue js 2 and my chart file was vue chart import was legacy but legacy doesnt work when i switched to import bla2 from vue-chartjs it worked. but your advice helped @kissu thx